# Error when adding NSManagedObjects subclasses

Tags: ios, swift, nsmanagedobject

When I try and add a NSManagedObject subclasses I get the following error

[image]

When I remove the subclasses they go away. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: It looks like Core Data is autogenerating files that you are also creating manually. In the inspector panel of your entity you can set _Codegen_ to _Manual/None_.

Comment: That's exactly what's happening, thanks... You should make that an answer

Answer (score 0):

There are a key strings:

[image]

Check, why you get this files twice.